# What would you consider the correct way to implement Use Cases/Repositories that return a Flow (Single Source of Truth + remote fetching)

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow, use-case

Suppose I have the following UseCase to fetch users as a flow

```
class FetchUsersFlowUseCase(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {

    operator fun invoke(): Flow<List<User>> {
        return userRepository.fetchUsersFlow()
    }
}
```

And a Repository with a function that fetches users as a Flow. When that function is called, an attempt to sync the local database (which is the Single Source of Truth) is also executed.

```
class UserRepositoryImpl(
    private val localUserDataSource: LocalUserDatasource,
    private val remoteUserDataSource: RemoteUserDatasource,
    private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope
) : UserRepository {

    override fun fetchUsersFlow(): Flow<List<User>> {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val remoteUsersResult = remoteUserDataSource.fetchUsers()
            if (remoteUsersResult.isSuccess) {
                // Success: update users locally
            } else {
                // What to do? 
                // How to correctly notify who observes that something wrong happened?
            }
        }

        return localUserDataSource.fetchUsersFlow()
    }
}
```

But if something unexpected happens (example: no Internet connection), how can I correctly notify who observes the Flow?

Comment: Check this medium article:[Modeling Retrofit Responses With Sealed Classes and Coroutines](https://proandroiddev.com/modeling-retrofit-responses-with-sealed-classes-and-coroutines-9d6302077dfe)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your result in an object, so consumers can determine success:

```
sealed interface Result {
  object Error: Result
  data class Success(val value: List<User>)
}
```

and

```
    override fun fetchUsersFlow(): Flow<Result> {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val remoteUsersResult = remoteUserDataSource.fetchUsers()
            if (remoteUsersResult.isSuccess) {
                yourFlow.emit(Result.Success(remoteUsersResult))
            } else {
                yourFlow.emit(Result.Error)
            }
        }

        return localUserDataSource.fetchUsersFlow()
    }
```

Then on the consumer side, you can

```
when(valueFromFlow) {
  Result.Error -> // handle it
  is Result.Success -> it.value // is your List<User>
}
```

You can add even more `Result` implementations to signal other cases, or make `Error` a data class too and give it fields holding details.

Comment: How would you connect `yourFlow` with `return localUserDataSource.fetchUsersFlow()`? They're not currently the same.

Comment: `localUserDataSource.fetchUsersFlow()` is the source? Then instead of `coroutineScope.launch`, use `.collect` on that flow, and `yourFlow` is simply a `MutableStateFlow()`.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with that code fix, please? Thank you very much : )

Comment: I'm not at all sure that's what you want. Which of the Flows is the source? Do you want to combine data from Local and Remote sources? Or do you `emit` into the Local flow? That last option feels strange.